# JQuery video controller - problem targeting relevant videos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video

I am creating a page to display a number of videos. I have created a video play button `video-item__button` to toggle play/pause its respective video, using JQuery. I have created a variable `$video` containing the location of the video that the button needs to target.

So I am saying - if the button is clicked - find a sibling element with `.video-item__video` class, then if paused - play/ if playing - pause.

However I am getting the following error message in the console:

```
"video-page-listing.js?ver=5.7:43 Uncaught TypeError: this.siblings is not a function"
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this issue?

```html
<article class="video-item">
    <div class="video-item__button"></div>
    <video class="video-item__video">
        <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</article>

<article class="video-item">
    <div class="video-item__button"></div>
    <video class="video-item__video">
        <source src="myvideo-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</article>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // When 'video-item__button' clicked   
        $('.video-item__button').click(function(){

            // Locate sibling 'video-item__video'            
            $video = (this).siblings('.video-item__video'); // doesn't work as Siblings not a function
            
            // If video paused: play
            if ($video.paused) {
                $video.play(); 
            } 
            // If video play: pause
            else {
                $video.pause(); 
            }
                
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: `(this)` is missing the dollar sign -> `$(this)`

Comment: Thanks - legend!!